# Why is a boolen value duplicated in the form serialize when checked = "checked"?

Tags: jquery, html, razor, editorfor, checkboxfor

I have a boolean value bound to CheckBoxFor or EditorFor (either one).

Here is the model declaration:

public bool IsActive { get; set; }

Here is the html (as you can see I've tried multiple variations):

```
<div>
@*@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } )*@

@*@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)*@

@*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)

</div>
```

I seem to have a side-effect that whenever I check the box, the IsActive value is duplicated in the form.  I alert the serialize before the post and this is what it looks like when the box is checked:

...&IsActive=true&IsActive=false...

When the box is not checked it's only ...&IsActive=false...

What could cause this behavior?  TIA

Comment: It's because ASP.Net `CheckBoxFor` controls are actually two elements. A checkbox and a hidden input. It's done this way so that a `false` value is always sent, regardless of the `checked` state of the checkbox.

Comment: Ok but I get the same result when I use EditorFor.  What do I need to do to fix it?  Or are you telling me it will send the right value in the model as is?